# Linux Debian 10 how to use c++ 20

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, debian-buster, gcc10

Well unluky as I am i had to a hard drive crash and had to reinstall my Linux. I tried to use vs studio code with C++20 but he does not recognize it. Below is my config.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-10 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-10",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "/home/johannes/Documents/CPP/projects/firstproject/.vscode/main.cpp",
                "-o",
                "-std=gnu++20",
                "/home/johannes/Documents/CPP/projects/firstproject/.vscode/main"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /bin/g++-10",
            
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to make a c++ program with Linux. How do i convince my system to use cpp 20? I installed gcc 10.2 but now I cant compile anything. And my last "__cplusplus" tells me its still using cpp14.
I do appretiate your time and wisdome.
I tried:
`gcc -o xxx xx.cpp`
and `gcc-10 -o xxx xx.cpp` .

---

````
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdWDdXJ.o: warning: relocation against `_ZSt4cout&apos; in read-only section `.text&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdWDdXJ.o: in function `main&apos;:
Test1.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `std::cout&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: Test1.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator&lt;&lt;(long)&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: Test1.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt; &gt;&amp; std::endl&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt; &gt;(std::basic_ostream&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt; &gt;&amp;)&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: Test1.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator&lt;&lt;(std::ostream&amp; (*)(std::ostream&amp;))&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: Test1.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `std::cout&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: Test1.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator&lt;&lt;(unsigned int)&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: Test1.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt; &gt;&amp; std::endl&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt; &gt;(std::basic_ostream&lt;char, std::char_traits&lt;char&gt; &gt;&amp;)&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: Test1.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator&lt;&lt;(std::ostream&amp; (*)(std::ostream&amp;))&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccdWDdXJ.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)&apos;:
Test1.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: Test1.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()&apos;
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
</pre>```

My Cppis below here.
`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
    std::cout << (unsigned int)__cplusplus << std::endl;
    return 0;
}`
````

Comment: Compile with the `-std=c++20` option.  (There's almost certainly a dupe for this but I can't find a good one right now.)

Comment: To enable C++20 support, add the command-line parameter ```-std=c++20```  (use -```std=c++2a``` in GCC 9 and earlier) to your g++ command line. Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to C++20 features, add ```-std=gnu++20``` .  https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Comment: I tried and it did not work, Postet the data in the Edit.

Comment: If you're compiling `C++` you need to invoke the compiler as `g++` *not* `gcc`.  Otherwise it links with the `C` runtime libraries resulting in the undefined symbol errors you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blockquote
> If you're compiling C++ you need to invoke the compiler as g++ not gcc. Otherwise it links with the C runtime libraries resulting in the undefined symbol errors you're seeing. – G.M. 17 mins ago

Thats it! Thanks! What a mess, the moment you do it the right way it suddenly works.

Answer (score 0):

While using `VSCode` This helped me.
With a `g++-9` Compiler

#### With `g++ 9`

Add : `-std=c++17` to the `args` array for `c++ 17` or

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-9 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-9",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-std=c++17"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

#### With `g++ 10`

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-10 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-10",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-std=c++20"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

#### Check the version

You can check the version with this small script, source --> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536462/13903942)

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;

    if (__cplusplus == 201703L) std::cout << "C++17\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201402L) std::cout << "C++14\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 201103L) std::cout << "C++11\n";
    else if (__cplusplus == 199711L) std::cout << "C++98\n";
    else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n";
}
```

### Related Questions:

- [How can I update my C++ version on VSCode to C++20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120301/how-can-i-update-my-c-version-on-vscode-to-c20)
- [What is the value of __cplusplus for C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456127/what-is-the-value-of-cplusplus-for-c17)
- [How to determine the version of the C++ standard used by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324658/how-to-determine-the-version-of-the-c-standard-used-by-the-compiler)
- [How can I compile with different version of g++ in c++ Autotools project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920978/how-can-i-compile-with-different-version-of-g-in-c-autotools-project)

### Support Docs

- [CXXdefaults.md](https://gist.github.com/ax3l/53db9fa8a4f4c21ecc5c4100c0d93c94)
- [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)